# How do you import a Compositing Node Set-up?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a Compositing node set-up for a lomography effect that I want to export or append to other blend files. Is there a way to do this?

I tried grouping the nodes, but the group wasn't appearing anywhere when I tried to append them in. (Node setup attached for whatever it's worth.)[image]

Comment: Select all, and press Ctrl+G, then append

Comment: I posted a quick text answer, if you need images or don't understand part of it, let me know.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this by making these nodes into a custom **Node Group** and then appending it to the file. To do this select all the nodes, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. *(I would recommend not including the Render Layer and Composite nodes, as they will be present in the new file)*

Now you can go to your new file and select *File > Append* and then navigate to the proper .blend file and then into the NodeGroup folder. Select the desired node group, and click **Append**.

Now you can go into your node editor and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Group* to select your node group. You can edit it using <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

While the existing answer is correct, here is something to think about if you still can't find your node tree in the file browser when you try to link it.

Pressing <kbd>N</kbd> in the workspace allows you to bring up the side panel where there are several options to rename the node; only the one under **Node > Properties** will change the reference name for linking.

[image]

My group I was trying to link was lost amidst a sea of NodeGroup.00n's and geometry nodes, (which are stored in the same place as the compositing).